# Highight cell based on current time

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Working on an hourly To-Do list.  I have a column (H) with the list hour (on the Hr) starting with 5am all the way until 11pm.
For Example:

```
5:00 AM
6:00 AM 
7:00 AM
8:00 AM
```

and so on....

I would like the 7:00 AM cell be highlighted when the current time is between 7-7:59 AM.  The then the next cell once it hits 8 and so on.

Thank you and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a custom Conditional Formatting rule.

Click on cell H1.

From the menu, choose ***Format > Conditional formatting***.

When the dialog box opens, choose "Add another rule."

In the "Apply to range" field, change `H1` to `H1:H`.

Under "Format Rules > Format cells if...," select "Custom formula is" from the dropdown menu.

In the "Value or formula" field, enter the following formula:

`=H1=MROUND(TIMEVALUE(NOW()),1/24)`

Set the "Formatting style" options as you like and click the "Done" button.